# Content Types of JSON in particular schema

Tags: json, json-schema

My application stores two different types of json data in s3.

For example: Schema-Foo and Schema-Bar.

Up to now I used the content-type `application/json` for both.

I would like to make a distinction between both types in the s3 storage.

I am unsure what the best way would be.

Is it possible to do something like `application/json-schema-foo` `application/json-schema-bar`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714383/what-are-all-the-possible-values-for-http-content-type-header

Comment: Sure you can. Take a look to the 'vnd' definition. `application/vnd+company.whatever+json`

Comment: @Laiv you use `application/vnd+company.whatever+json` and User Hans-Martin Mosner uses `application/json; schema=foo`. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Any, as soon as they meet your needs and introduce the less complexity possible. The @Hans-Martin' solution is probably the simplest. It's up to you to decide if that simplicity meet your needs. I would probably try his first. I  just wanted you to have alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use content-type parameters as in

```
application/json; schema=foo
application/json; schema=bar
```

I don't know whether adding user-defined parameters is officially blessed, but as long as you're talking between your own pieces of software who is going to punish you?